getent and id do not agree for freeipa user
I have a freeipa server with users which have different uid and gid.
For example, I have user alice with uid 1024 and gid 1026. User bob has uid 1026 and gid 1028. Yes, confusing, but that's how I inherited the system and how all files are labeled in our NFS storage system.
The issue is that id does not correctly resolve group names and operations such as chown yield wrong results.
Currently, id alice outputs uid=1024(alice) gid=1026(bob) and id bob outputs uid=1026(bob) gid=1028(carol). When checking in freeipa, then alice indeed has UID: 1024 and GID: 1026 and bob has UID: 1026 and GID:1028.
Problem is when I run chown bob:bob testfile, then testfile has uid 1026 and gid 1026, even though gid 1026 belongs to alice, not bob!
getent is a whole other story: getent group alice returns alice:*:1024: (wrong) and getent passwd alice returns alice:*:1024:1026:alice doe:/home/alice:/bin/sh.
Where does the lookup of groupids and groupnames fail and how to fix it?
I could also think about changing gids for every user, but then I would also have to touch all files on our NFS storage to adjust the gids. And all local scratchpads on all servers, so this is not a road I would like to take.
EDIT:
Just set up a new fedora 40 as test server, and all results are the same.
As requested in the comments, here is my /etc/nsswitch
# Generated by authselect
# Do not modify this file manually, use authselect instead. Any user changes will be overwritten.
# You can stop authselect from managing your configuration by calling 'authselect opt-out'.
# See authselect(8) for more details.

# In order of likelihood of use to accelerate lookup.
passwd:     files sss systemd
shadow:     files
group:      files [SUCCESS=merge] sss [SUCCESS=merge] systemd
hosts:      files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] myhostname dns
services:   files sss
netgroup:   files sss
sudoers:    files sss
automount:  files sss

aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files

alice and bob do not have local user accounts. In fact, root is the only non-system local account. So here is my /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:Super User:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/usr/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:Kernel Overflow User:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
tss:x:59:59:Account used for TPM access:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-coredump:x:998:998:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-oom:x:997:997:systemd Userspace OOM Killer:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:193:193:systemd Resolver:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:996:996:systemd Time Synchronization:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
polkitd:x:114:114:User for polkitd:/:/sbin/nologin
chrony:x:995:995:chrony system user:/var/lib/chrony:/sbin/nologin
rpc:x:32:32:Rpcbind Daemon:/var/lib/rpcbind:/sbin/nologin
rpcuser:x:29:29:RPC Service User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
unbound:x:994:994:Unbound DNS resolver:/var/lib/unbound:/sbin/nologin
setroubleshoot:x:993:993:SELinux troubleshoot server:/var/lib/setroubleshoot:/usr/sbin/nologin
abrt:x:173:173::/etc/abrt:/sbin/nologin
cockpit-ws:x:992:992:User for cockpit web service:/nonexisting:/sbin/nologin
cockpit-wsinstance:x:991:991:User for cockpit-ws instances:/nonexisting:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/usr/share/empty.sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
dnsmasq:x:990:990:Dnsmasq DHCP and DNS server:/var/lib/dnsmasq:/usr/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:72:72:tcpdump:/:/usr/sbin/nologin

and /etc/group
root:x:0:
bin:x:1:
daemon:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mem:x:8:
kmem:x:9:
wheel:x:10:
cdrom:x:11:
mail:x:12:
man:x:15:
dialout:x:18:
floppy:x:19:
games:x:20:
tape:x:33:
video:x:39:
ftp:x:50:
lock:x:54:
audio:x:63:
users:x:100:
nobody:x:65534:
dbus:x:81:
utmp:x:22:
utempter:x:35:
tss:x:59:
printadmin:x:999:
wbpriv:x:88:
input:x:104:
kvm:x:36:
render:x:105:
sgx:x:106:
systemd-journal:x:190:
systemd-coredump:x:998:
systemd-oom:x:997:
systemd-resolve:x:193:
systemd-timesync:x:996:
polkitd:x:114:
chrony:x:995:
rpc:x:32:
rpcuser:x:29:
unbound:x:994:
setroubleshoot:x:993:
abrt:x:173:
cockpit-ws:x:992:
cockpit-wsinstance:x:991:
sshd:x:74:
dnsmasq:x:990:
tcpdump:x:72:
plocate:x:989:


What does your /etc/nsswitch file look like? Do you have local entries for alice and bob in /etc/passwd and/or /etc/group?

Ok, I know the issue now: freeipa is creating private groups for users upon creation. These private groups do not take into consideration the gid, but simply use the uid. For example, when ipa user-add alice --uid=1024 --gid=1026, a private group named alice will be created with gid=1024. Similarly for bob. Private groups can viewed using ipa group-find --private. Modification is not directly possible, but some ldap magic works. Or patching freeipa. Will write an answer when I have fully used my approach to fix the issue.

If you don't need user private groups, you should not create users with UPG defaults.
$ ipa help user-add |grep noprivate
  --noprivate           Don't create user private group

For already created users you can detach their UPG groups. There is no way back, though.
$ ipa help group-detach 
Usage: ipa [global-options] group-detach GROUP-NAME [options]

Detach a managed group from a user.


